# How do I get Apache's mod_autoindex 'AddDescription' directive to act only on a top level directory?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a large filesystem full of files that I am 'sharing' via apache2 using mod_autoindex.

The root level folder of the server contains five directories and I would like to have a comment against each folder in the *Description* column at the root level, and only at the root level. For example, the root folder could look like this:

```
Index of /

Name       Last modified      Size   Description
george/    27-Feb-2011 15:50     -   
john/      27-Feb-2011 16:05     -   
paul/      19-Jun-2011 19:12     -   
pete/      12-Mar-2011 18:57     -   
ringo/     31-Oct-2011 18:42     -
```

If I add `AddDescription "Can't do a drum roll" /ringo/` to httpd.conf nothing happens.

In digging around with Google I have found that you should drop the leading slash. I add `AddDescription "Can't do a drum roll" ringo/` and I then get that description against every single file and subdirectory in the 'ringo' directory, which I don't want.

Furthermore, I don't get that description against the *ringo/* folder in the root level listing, which is what I actually want.

I noted that in the apache2 documentation, the file descriptor in that directive is *"a file extension, partial filename, wild-card expression or full filename for files to describe"*, so I can see why it's going through the full directory structure, but what I really want is to be able to have a description against the five top level directories and no-where else.

I'm assuming that regular expressions aren't part of the syntax, because the documentation doesn't mention it and also because it didn't work. Mind you, the documentation says that you need the leading slash and that isn't the case either.

Answer (score 1):

If the `DocumentRoot` of your site is `/var/www`, you can try the ruleset:

```
AddDescription "&nbsp;" */www/*/ringo
AddDescription "&nbsp;" */www/ringo?*
AddDescription "Can't do a drum roll" */www/ringo
```

The trick is to use `"&nbsp;"`, which is the default content for a file/folder that doesn't match anything, to nullify any file/folder that matches `ringo` but is in a deeper directory or has a suffix after `ringo`.

For a detailed explanation you have to know the actual rules of AddDescription, which is kind of complicated:

Syntax: `AddDescription string file [file] ...`

- `string` must not be empty. An error occurs if `""` is provided.
- `file` can contain wildcards `*` ot `?`. Both of them can match `/`.
- `file` starting with `/` matches nothing.
- `file` containing `/` matches any part of the whole path of the accessed file.

  - The "whole path" seems to be the absolute path on the server. For example, if the `DocumentRoot` of a site `example.com` is `/var/www`, the whole path of the page `http://example.com/myfolder/myfile.html` is `/var/www/myfolder/myfile.html`.
  - In this case, `file` will be implicitly prepended a `*/` to ensure a full match of the specified folder name. For example, `myfolder/myfile.html` actually means `*/myfolder/myfile.html`, and as a result it matches `http://example.com/myfolder/myfile.html` (`/var/www/myfolder/myfile.html`) and doesn't match `http://example.com/prefixedmyfolder/myfile.html` (`/var/www/prefixedmyfolder/myfile.html`).
  - There is no trailing `/` in the file name of a folder. For example, `myfolder/subfolder/` (`*/myfolder/subfolder/`) does not match the folder `http://example.com/myfolder/subfolder` (`/var/www/myfolder/subfolder`) but `myfolder/subfolder` (`*/myfolder/subfolder`) does.
- Otherwise, `file` matches any part of the file name of the accessed file.

  - For example, `hpin` matches `http://example.com/phpinfo.php` (`phpinfo.php`) or `http://example.com/subdir/phpinfo.php` (`phpinfo.php`), and does not match `http://example.com/phpinfo/whatever.php` (`whatever.php`).
- The first match applies first and any following match will be skipped.

ref: [Apache 2.4 doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription)

Answer (score 0):

Is the structure of the root level static and will have those five directories, and only those five directories?

Then the easiest way might be to fake it. Just create a static HTML page that looks like it was generated by `mod_autoindex`. Add the descriptions by hand to that static page. Let the rest of the pages be generated by `mod_autoindex`.

Comment: That's not a bad idea actually. In fact I will probably do that. I would still like to see if this can be done via mod_autoindex for the sake of a web service that is simpler to operate (in case I do change the root directory), but that's pretty good!

Answer (score 0):

Also drop the trailing slash, and you're done:

```
AddDescription "Can't do a drum roll" ringo
```